# Rails Can't Display Google Maps Embedded API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, google-maps-api-3

In my rails app, I am trying to use the Google Maps embedded API.

Everthing is working fine when i use:

```
    <iframe width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
      src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDBvzq5WsidARhAZ0821MB1iAMTPnHiamI&q=3177 shawnee ct,cameron park,ca,95682" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

This works and the map displays. But that is with explicitly saying the address.

My Model has a `:full_address` field and a `:longitude` and `:latitude` fields.

I am trying to do the following:

```
    <iframe width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
      src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDBvzq5WsidARhAZ0821MB1iAMTPnHiamI&q=#{@job.jobsite.full_address}" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
```

But its not recognizing my rails object of `@job.jobsite.full_address`. I already know that there is an address stored there, and I tested it with the static map API and everything worked fine.

But when i try to render the map it gives me the error:

> The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request.
>   Invalid 'q' parameter.

Can anyone tell me why `@job.jobsite.full_address` is not working in side that url I am providing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly replace your location with ruby tag

```
<iframe width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDBvzq5WsidARhAZ0821MB1iAMTPnHiamI&q=<%=@job.jobsite.full_address%>" allowfullscreen>
```